# Splitting a prefab into two

Tags: unity, motion

[image]

These hands are in a single prefab. I want to split this into two so that I can make bones for each of them separately and use them with leap motion.

How can make each of these hands as a single prefab? Also, I'm using Unity 2018.

Comment: If they are together in a same Mesh / Model, you will have to separate them in the modeling software you are using. If they are already each one a GameObject, create 2 prefabs, and drag each one into its respective prefab (you can also drag the GameObjects into the Project's folder to create the prefabs).

Comment: do you know how to do it either in maya or blender ? because when i it I'll loose the texture